# Escaping golang template in Jinja2 template

Tags: go, ansible, jinja2

I have the following tasks:

```
- name: Set default log options for Splunk
  set_fact:
    log_options_base:
       tag: "{{ '{{' }}.ImageName{{ '}}' }}/{{ '{{' }}.Name{{ '}}' }}/{{ '{{' }}.ID{{ '}}' }}"
       splunk-token: "{{ splunk_token }}"
       splunk-url: "{{ splunk_url }}"
       splunk-format: "json"
       splunk-index: "my-dx"
       labels: "{{ env }}"
  when:
    - log_driver is defined
    - log_driver == 'splunk'
- name: Set extendend log options for Splunk
  set_fact:
    log_options_ext: "{{ log_options_base | combine({ 'env': NODE_ENV }) }}"
  when:
     - log_options_base != ""
```

Unfortunately I'm having the following issue:

`template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: {{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}\n\n`

`"The conditional check 'log_options_base != \"\"' failed.`

The issue is definitely with the golang template but it is already escaped in my case.

Any idea?

Comment: You can try with different template delimiters, so escape may not be needed.

Comment: @jeevatkm can you elaborate please?

Comment: By default Go template delimiters is `{{ }}`, you have an option to change it. For example: to `[[ ]]` via [template.Delims](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Delims).

Comment: @jeevatkm it's docker

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get your point. If it's a Go template either text or html, you can choose different delimiters so that it won't get collide with other usage.

Comment: this go template is a options tag used in `docker run` command

Answer (score 2):

`when` statement is a Jinja2 expression itself, so Ansible tries to evaluate your string once again.

You should be good with [!unsafe](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings) typing in this case:

```
- name: Set default log options for Splunk
  set_fact:
    log_options_base:
       tag: !unsafe "{{.ImageName}}/{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
```

But I haven't used this syntax trick much, so there may be some side effects, test it before production use.

P.S. why do you compare dict var `log_options_base` with empty string in `log_options_base != ""`? May be you want `is defined` test?

Comment: the error is now gone but the `tag` property is rendered like this `u'tag': u'//'`

Comment: Just tested it with ansible 2.2.1, seems to be working as expected. What version are you on?

Comment: 2.2.2.0 ansible

Comment: Yeah, there were regressions introduced while Ansible team has been fighting with CVEs. If you put intermediate debug, you'll notice that `{{...}}` are replaced with jinja2 comments, leaving you with just forward slashes after double templating. Try with 2.2.1 or 2.3.1